# Multiple circles drawn SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm working on simple game which will based on paiting background by player. In left and right corner there will be buttons which will move character to left or right. I've already implemented that (character is moving and lefts painted background behind), but with adding another circles fps's drops really fast. Is there any solution to that?

```
    import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var playerDot:PlayerDot = PlayerDot(imageNamed:"player")
    var isTurningLeft:Bool = false
    var isTurningRight:Bool = false
    var lastLocation:CGPoint = CGPoint()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Helvetica")
        myLabel.name = "left"
        myLabel.text = "Left"
        myLabel.fontSize = 30
        myLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Left
        myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMinX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMinY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(myLabel)

        let myLabel2 = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Helvetica")
        myLabel2.name = "right"
        myLabel2.text = "Right"
        myLabel2.fontSize = 30
        myLabel2.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Right
        myLabel2.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMinY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(myLabel2)

        playerDot.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame)/2, y:CGRectGetMinY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(playerDot)
    }



    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if let theName = self.nodeAtPoint(location).name {
                if theName == "left" {
                   isTurningLeft = true
                    isTurningRight = false
                }
                else if theName == "right" {
                    isTurningRight = true
                    isTurningLeft = false
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if let theName = self.nodeAtPoint(location).name {
                if theName == "left" {
                    isTurningLeft = false
                }
                else if theName == "right" {
                    isTurningRight = false
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if let theName = self.nodeAtPoint(location).name {
                if theName == "left" {
                    isTurningLeft = false
                }
                else if theName == "right" {
                    isTurningRight = false
                }
            }
        }
    }


    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        if(isTurningLeft){
            playerDot.increaseAngle()
        } else if (isTurningRight){
           playerDot.decreaseAngle()
        }
        //calculates new character position based on angle of movement changed
        playerDot.updatePosition()
        drawCircle()
    }

    func drawCircle(){
        if(distanceFromCGPoints(lastLocation, b: playerDot.position)>2){
        let circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10 )
        circle.position = playerDot.position
        circle.fillColor = SKColor.orangeColor()
        circle.strokeColor = SKColor.orangeColor()
        self.addChild(circle)
        lastLocation = playerDot.position
        }
    }

    func distanceFromCGPoints(a:CGPoint,b:CGPoint)->CGFloat{
        return sqrt(pow(a.x-b.x,2)+pow(a.y-b.y,2));
    }

    func random() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
    }

    func random(min min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return random() * (max - min) + min
    }
}
```

EDIT:
drawCircle with SKShapeNode replaced with SKSpriteNote

```
func drawCircle(){
    if(distanceFromCGPoints(lastLocation, b: playerDot.position)>2){
    let playerDot2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"player")
    playerDot2.position = playerDot.position
    self.addChild(playerDot2)
    lastLocation = playerDot.position
    }
}
```

Comment: An `SKShapeNode` is not rendered in batches like `SKSpriteNode`.. So each shape node you create requires at least one draw call (in your case even more), and that is the source of performance issues you are currently experiencing.  As you can see, and according to the docs an [SKShapeNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/) should be used sparingly.

Comment: @Whirlwind so there is other solution how I can replace SKShapeNode with some thing else? I think that if I will use SKSpriteNode with image of circle same problem will occur because of quantity of Nodes

Comment: @Whirlwind I've replaced SKShapeNode with SKSpriteNode and after adding about 300 nodes frame rate also drops

Comment: Add the full code to show how you create an SKSpriteNode...

Comment: @Whirlwind added above, only one method has changed

Comment: So, the next optimisation you can make  is to create `SKSpriteNode` from a texture. `SKSpriteNode` `imageNamed` method is creating a new texture every time. Also I never stated that `SKSpriteNode` is the best way to go for solving this, but it is certainly a much performant way in compare to `SKShapeNode`. Look at this  SO [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30448038/3402095) given by Skyler Lauren. It should help you to reduce resource usage a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having frame rate drops then some parts of your code are slowing down execution too much. You need to optimise your code. Use Instruments (Time Profiler) to find out which lines/functions are causing problems speed wise. If you have never used it before read up on it and use it a couple times to get the gist, then I recommend watching the WWDC video [Profiling In-Depth](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/412/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit (switching to `SKSpriteNode`), this is how you could do it:

Declare a texture as a property of your scene. This way, you load it once and reuse it later:

`let yourTexture = SKTextureAtlas(named: "yourAtlas").textureNamed("yourTexture")`

Then in your `drawCircle` method:

```
func drawCircle(){
    if(distanceFromCGPoints(lastLocation, b: playerDot.position)>2){
    let playerDot2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: yourTexture)
    playerDot2.position = playerDot.position
    self.addChild(playerDot2)
    lastLocation = playerDot.position
    }
}
```

This way (by using `SKSpriteNode` instead of `SKShapeNode`)  you have reduced number of draw calls required to render all those circles. Also because you are reusing the same texture, instead of allocating it every time using `imageNamed` you have reduced greatly an amount of memory that app consumes. Now, SpriteKit can render hundreds of nodes @60 fps if those nodes are rendered in batches. Still there is a limit before fps start dropping. And that depends on a device.