# SpriteKit retaining memory after I leave game

Tags: swift, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, sprite-kit

So I am developing an app that includes a SpriteKit game. What I noticed is that after I start and close the game the memory keeps increasing as shown on the graph below:

[image]

I am presenting the game from a View Controller using a modal presentation. So the question is:
Is there a way to completely remove the scene from memory?

I am tapping a close button on the View Controller to dismiss it. The `scene.quitGame()` method basically deallocates all nodes, actions etc. In an ideal world I wouldn't even need to do any of that as there would be a magic command that gets rid of the `SKScene` completely.

```
@IBAction func quit(_ sender: UIButton) {
    scene.quitGame()
    scene.removeFromParent()
    self.removeFromParentViewController()
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    scene = nil
}
```

EDIT: I present the scene from viewDidLoad with the following code:

```
scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
let skView = view as! SKView
skView.showsFPS = false
skView.showsNodeCount = false
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
if let heroImage2 = heroImage2, let myImage = myImage, let monsterImage = monsterImage{
    scene.addPicture(img: heroImage2, myImage: myImage,monsterImage: monsterImage, bigMonsterImage: bigMonsterImage!)
}
skView.presentScene(scene)
scene.viewController = self
```

EDIT 2 - I commented out the call to this method that includes a repeat forever action and the leak seems to go away

```
   func createHerosAction(duration: Double = 5.0){
        run(SKAction.repeatForever(
            SKAction.sequence([
                SKAction.run(addHero),
                SKAction.wait(forDuration: duration)
                ])
        ), withKey:"createHeros")
    }



func addHero() {
    // Create sprite
    if(heroImage == nil){
        heroImage = UIImage(named: "hero")
    }

    let Texture = SKTexture(image: heroImage!)
    let hero = SKSpriteNode(texture:Texture)
    hero.size.width = size.width * 0.17
    hero.size.height = hero.size.width
    hero.name = "hero"
    hero.zPosition = 2

    let heroSide = arc4random_uniform(2)

    hero.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: hero.size) // 1
    hero.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true // 2
    hero.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Hero // 3
    hero.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Projectile // 4
    hero.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None // 5

    let actualY = random(min: size.height*0.3 + hero.size.height/2 + size.height * 0.12, max: size.height - hero.size.height/2 - size.height * 0.15)

    let pointRightOfScreen = CGPoint(x: size.width + hero.size.width/2, y: actualY)
    let pointLeftOfScreen = CGPoint(x:  -hero.size.width/2, y: actualY)

    if(heroSide == 0){
        hero.position = pointRightOfScreen
    }else{
        hero.position = pointLeftOfScreen
    }

    addChild(hero)

    let actualDuration = random(min: CGFloat(2.0), max: CGFloat(5.0))

    var actionMove = SKAction()

    if(heroSide == 0){
        actionMove = SKAction.move(to: pointLeftOfScreen, duration: TimeInterval(actualDuration))
    }else{
        actionMove = SKAction.move(to: pointRightOfScreen, duration: TimeInterval(actualDuration))
    }

    let numberOfUpsAndDown = random(min: CGFloat(1.0), max: CGFloat(10.0))
    let variance = random(min: CGFloat(-70.0), max: CGFloat(70.0))


    let mvHero = moveHeroUpAndDown(node: hero, variance: variance,duration: actualDuration/numberOfUpsAndDown)

    let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()


    let loseLifeAction = loseLife(node: hero)

    hero.run(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, loseLifeAction, actionMoveDone]), withKey: "moveHero")
    hero.run(mvHero, withKey: "UpAndDown")


}
```

EDIT 3: The leak seems to be on this SKAction that gets called above. After I removed this action the leak stopped.

```
   func loseLife(node: SKSpriteNode) -> SKAction{

    let loseALifeAction = SKAction.run(){

        if(self.gamePaused == false){
            self.playSound(fileName: "losesound.wav")

            if(self.lives > 0){
                self.updateLives(newValue: self.lives - 1, lostLife: true)
                //self.lives -= 1
            }

            print("lives: \(self.lives)")

            if(self.lives <= 0){
                print("hit me")
                node.run(self.loseGame())
            }
        }
    }
    return loseALifeAction
}
```

Comment: Is this view controller being repeatedly shown and dismissed? Or is the view controller up all the time? Does the scene define a delegate that the view controller is setting?

Comment: The view controller that is holding the scene is being shown and dismissed.

Comment: I did not define a delegate. How does that work?

Comment: I tried: class GameViewController: UIViewController, SKSceneDelegate { and
       scene?.delegate = viewController

Comment: Generally, the scene as you have it above should be deallocated the moment it gets nulled out like you're doing. If you get the feeling your scene is not being deallocated, that means something else has a reference to your scene. Can you provide the code where the scene is allocated?

Comment: I will edit the OP to make it clearer

Comment: Try using Instruments to look at memory allocations.  It will tell you what kind of objects are using the most space and a history of how/why they are being held in memory.

Comment: `scene.removeFromParent()` doesn't have an effect. Scene is a root node and it doesn't have a parent, means its `parent` property is always nil.

Comment: If you are able to upload a project on the GitHub, that would be nice. If not, then override deinit methods of every class you use. Make sure that you don't use strong self inside of blocks that are part of action sequences that repeat forever. Use capture lists for that. Etc etc :) That is why I asked for a project on Git :) You have to look at many places...

Comment: If you are beginner and not familiar with Instruments, you may try to [debug memory graph visually](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-visual-memory-debugger/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help @Whirlwind. Based on one of your comments I decided to comment out the code that included a repeat forever action and the leak goes away. See EDIT 2. Please let me know what you'd change there to fix this error.

Comment: Also, you said you  modally present a game...I might be wrong, but that sounds to me, like you are presenting a modal view controller over a current one, and that new view controller presents the scene... If this is a case, then you are complicating things unnecessary by mixing UIKit and SpriteKit that much. Transitions can be easily done using `SKTransitions`. You don't need multiple view controllers, but rather just one, and this will work in many situations... Take a look at this implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35409586/3402095 That would be a preferred way in SpriteKit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your comments, you should use [capture lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html):

```
func createHerosAction(duration: Double = 5.0){

        run(SKAction.repeatForever(
            SKAction.sequence([

                SKAction.run {[unowned self] in
                    self.addHero()
                },
                SKAction.wait(forDuration: duration)
                ])
        ), withKey:"createHeros")
    }
```

It is a big topic, but I suggest you to start reading the link I have posted, because it has everything explained in detail starting from "How ARC works", "What are Capture Lists" to the weak and unowned keywords. I wrote few times about this already, as well as many others on this site, and it is a big topic, so I will skip that this time :)

Comment: Thanks again for all your amazing help @Whirlwind. This still doesn't solve my issue but we're closing in on it. Please see EDIT 3.

Comment: @JPAquino I re-create this in my own project, and your `createHerosAction` makes a leak - means scene can't deallocate after the transition. Well, the usual `SKTransition`. That is why you need `[unowned self]`... I will look into your new edit... By the way, why do you create an `UIImage`, in order to create `SKTexture` in order to create `SKSpriteNode` from a texture? Just go with `SKTexture(named:)`. You can even go with `SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:)` but that method has be proven [to be not that performant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30448038/3402095)...

Comment: @JPAquino Try putting `[unowned self]` in that closure as well. You have to keep in mind that when you use strong self inside of a closure, the closure will capture that self.

Comment: BOOOM that solves it. Thanks again for all your help and explanations, you're my hero.

Comment: @JPAquino Nice, glad to hear it worked. Still, I would strongly recommend you to take a peek into how ARC works,because you have to think about memory management from the beginning of the project. It is easier like that, rather than solving/debugging many things when project is almost done.

Comment: Yes I did read the link you posted and definitely learned a lot about it the past couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its an internal SpriteKit leak holding the ViewController in memory. We found that SpriteKit appeared to retain the Scene and SKView after dismissing the viewController.

In our case we began specifically presenting a nil scene when the game was over, right after we presented the game over screen.

```
    // Remove the game scene to stop game code and free up memory
    if let skView = view as? SKView {
        skView.presentScene(nil)
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I tried adding this to my quitGame() method on the game scene and to the quit method on the viewController but memory leak remains unchanged.

Comment: presentScene(nil) will only set a scene property to nil on an SKView. If some other instances have a strong reference to the scene, the leak will remain...In the case that scene is the leaking object of course :)

Comment: Do you have any closures that could retain a strong reference to "self"?  Like in a run(block) action etc.?

Comment: We did not. I was able to recreate the issue in a simple single scene test project and submitted a radar. This was about a year ago so its likely fixed. But it looks like this gentleman's problem was different in nature. But just incase someone stumbles here with our issue I'll leave it up.